# Dense-Sparse Matrix Multiplication routine instead if sparse-dense multiplication

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I have a problem where I need to multiply a dense matrix by a sparse matrix. The function "**mkl_?csrmm**" in intel-mkl asks for the first matrix to be sparse and the second to be dense. But my case is opposite.

Problem: **C = A * B + C** , where **A** is dense and **B** is sparse.

I know that I can use "mkl_?csrmm" after taking the transpose of both matrices A and B but the transpose operation will be costly. Is there a better way or existing routine for dense-sparse matrix multiplication?

I am beginner so kindly forgive for mistakes. Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Shailesh Tripathi

Comment: it seems you're pretty much screwed according to this post https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/277570  .  But you CAN avoid one transposition (the one of the sparse matrix) by using the transa ='T' argument in csrmm

Comment: Since you are using C++, why don't you just use some template library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze)?